# Maximize a window with python

Tags: python-3.x

Im doing a program that requires to re-open an existing tab of an application that is already running (in my case Minecraft) because the program is used on that application.

Right now im using the mouse library to make the cursor move to the app icon in the task bar and click on it to open it, but I want to do it in another way.
This is the code im using for it

```
import mouse

def open_tab():
#coordinates of the tab on screen
  x = 785
  y = 1055
  mouseclick(x,y)

def mouseclick(x,y) #click on the specified x and y screen coordinates
  mouse.move(x,y,absolute=True,duration=0)
  mouse.click('left')

open_tab()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyautogui simply. For changing windows you can use alt+tab and configure it for your specific usage
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

```
import pyautogui
#selecting the window
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','tab')
#maximizing the window
pyautogui.press("f11")
```

Comment: But I dont want to maximize the python app, I want to maximize an external aplication, in my case minecraft

Comment: Ok, make alt+tab with pyautogui.hotkey('alt','tab') and use the code on top. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, it work as intended

Comment: Can you approve my answer please?